# Passing random.nextInt() as a parameter causes strange problems

Tags: java, random, parameters

I am trying to pass a random integer to a constructor.

```
hotels[2] = new Hotel(random.nextInt(10)+30, random.nextInt()+100, 
                random.nextInt()+20, random.nextInt()+200, 
                random.nextInt()+10, random.nextInt()+300);
```

However, in the DataPoint constructor, the values being passed inside were ridiculous, i.e.

```
Params 1, 3, 5:      38   -695807826   -2078518332
```

Getting `-695807826` makes no sense. The number should be between 20 and 40, because of `random.nextInt()+20`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply because after the first argument, you forgot to add a parameter to `nextInt`

Your call should be:

```
hotels[2] = new Hotel(random.nextInt(10)+30, random.nextInt(10)+100, 
                random.nextInt(10)+20, random.nextInt(10)+200, 
                random.nextInt(10)+10, random.nextInt(10)+300);
```

Comment: oy I don't know how I missed that. http://giphy.com/gifs/smh-reaction-toy-story-avFEkQo2I73fa

Answer (score 4):

If you do something like `random.nextInt()+300` and the result of the `random.nextInt()` call is within 300 of the maximum integer value, you'll get overflow and the result will be interpreted as a negative number.

Answer (score -3):

I realized the problem was calling

```
random.nextInt()+20
```

inside the parameter list.

When I generate random numbers before the method call, I get normal results.

```
        a = random.nextInt(10)+30;
        b = random.nextInt(10)+20;
        c = random.nextInt(10)+10;
        ...
        hotels[2] = new Hotel(a, b, c, ...);
```

Comment: You do realize that the example you give here is different than that stated in your question, right?  `random.nextInt()+10` and `random.nextInt(10)+10` don't do the same thing...